# Write a program to compare 2 versions using perl

Tags: perl

Is the below program correct to compare two versions? 
say v1 = 3.0.1 and v2 = 4.5.5

```
sub VerChecker
{
my $v1 = shift;
my $v2 = shift;

my @v1_parts = split (/./, $v1);
my @v2_parts = split (/./, $v2);

for( my $i = 0; $i < @v1_parts; $i++ ) 
{
if( $v1_parts[$i] < $v2_parts[$i] ) 
{
return -1;
}
elsif( $v1_parts[$i] > $v2_parts[$i] )
{
return 1;
}
}

 # equal !
 return 0;
}
```

Can you correct the above code

Comment: Well, is it correct or isn't it? What doesn't work exactly? What did you try to fix it?

Comment: Why not write some tests for it, using [one of the many excellent test modules](https://metacpan.org/pod/Task::Kensho#Task::Kensho::Testing:-Testing)?

Comment: It doesn't return any value wherein it should return some value since i had mentioned v1 = 3.0.1 and v2 = 4.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub ver_checker {
    my ($v1, $v2) = @_;

    my @v1_parts = split(/\./, $v1);
    my @v2_parts = split(/\./, $v2);

    my $num_parts = scalar @v1_parts;
    if (scalar @v2_parts > $num_parts) {
        $num_parts = scalar @v2_parts;
    }

    for my $part (0 .. $num_parts-1) {
        $v1_parts[$part] = sprintf("%04d", $v1_parts[$part] // 0);
        $v2_parts[$part] = sprintf("%04d", $v2_parts[$part] // 0);
    }

    return join('', @v1_parts) cmp join('', @v2_parts);
}

print ver_checker('3.0.1', '4.5.5')."\n";
print ver_checker('3.0', '4.5.5')."\n";
print ver_checker('3.0.1', '4')."\n";
print ver_checker('5', '4')."\n";
```

A few things to mention:

1. `use strict; use warnings;` always
2. Camel Case Isn't Fun Anymore. Use lowercase_and_underscores
3. Escape literals in regular expressions. Your split needed to escape the period
4. I find that when comparing something dotted like this, it's easier to pad everything out and compare the string. Your code only considered if the version number was three dotted numbers. I made it more portable by making it choose the longest dotted number and pad both out (ie. `3.1` vs `5.0.1` essentially becomes `3.1.0` vs `5.0.1`, and pads to `000300010000` vs `000500000001`. `cmp` returns your `-1/0/1` value.

To clarify why your split wasn't working:
Your split needed to escape the period. You were splitting on every character, which meant there were no captures. Run this script to see for yourself.

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $foo = 'a.b.c';
my @split1 = split(/./, $foo); # gives []
my @split2 = split(//, $foo); # gives ['a', '.', 'b', '.', 'c']
my @split3 = split(/\./, $foo); # gives [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
print Dumper [ \@split1, \@split2, \@split3 ];
```

Comment: why we need to emphasis on using strict and warning always ?

Comment: strict and warnings, to highlight errors in code at compile/translation time.
I generally code review samples that I contribute to, and am sorry if you feel pecked from this #1 rule.

Comment: between is there any issue with my program can you tell me why its not returning any value

Comment: Your split needed to escape the period. You were splitting on every character, which meant there were no captures.

Comment: can you share your i/p for this question as well     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427284/given-the-following-subroutine-how-would-you-call-below-subroutine-so-that-it-w

Comment: didn't get you can you elaborate also in the other question which i posted the $rest{'message'} doesnt return the value why is it ?

Comment: Accept this answer and I might take a look

Comment: Can someone explain the significance of the "// 0" in the sprintf? On my system, that   gives an error 
`Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/ 0) <-- HERE ;
        4 = sprintf("%04d", 4 / at `
 It works just well without the "// 0".
perl version v5.16.1